# Can stack 2 sidebars with float:right

Tags: html, css, css-float, stack, sidebar

I've been looking almost everywhere trying to find a solution..

Anyways, I'm trying to "stack" two sidebars on top off each other,but the second one can't get under the first one unless the content I have next to the sidebar is higher than the first sidebar(weird explanation but I couldn't figure out any other way to explain it.)

Both of them are inside 2 different  tags with the same id which is:

```
#designsidebar {
float:right;
width:155px;
padding:10px;
border:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#333330;
background-color:#171715;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both of them to be in the same tag, and float that tag to the right. Also, you should never have more than one of any given `id` on a page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use the same id for 2 different things. It's called an ID for a reason. You should use a class instead. Best practices aside, I'm not sure I understood your question, but you may need to set your sidebar as `position:absolute;`, and set the `z-index` of them accordingly. Using a javascript most likely to change that `z-index` when it meets your criteria. Not sure what the criteria is, so hard to say other possible ways to work with it.